# Where clause error in passing parameter to laravel 5 query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting data using the below query. When I pass the parameter to `where` clause, it converts the parameter to a question mark `?`.

```
$productDatas = DB::table('products')
                         ->select('products.*','products.id as pid','product_features.*','product_features.id as pfid')
                         ->join('product_features','product_features.product_id','=','products.id')
                         ->join('categories','categories.id','=','products.cat_id','left');

if($value == 13) {
    // $value = intval($value);
    $productData = $productDatas->where('product_features.'.$field,'<',$value)->toSql();
    dd($productData);  
} else {
    $productData = $productDatas->where('product_features.'.$field,'=',$value)->get();
}
```

Output of query:

```
"select `products`.*, `products`.`id` as `pid`, `product_features`.*, `product_features`.`id` as `pfid` 
from `products` 
inner join `product_features` on `product_features`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
left join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `products`.`cat_id` 
where `product_features`.`primary_camera` < ?"
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is not getting actual data from database

Comment: What is the `dd($productData)` doing?  In your `else` block you are calling the `->get()` function but you aren't doing that in the `if` block.

Comment: I added an explanation about the `?` issue. It may not be the answer for the question as you haven't asked the question properly. It is just to demolish the fuzz about the `?` issue. Please Update your question with you intended result and the error you get so we could further comment.

Comment: Updated title for concision and code format for readability, breaking lines from long horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry about the `?` mark. It's how laravel indicate you there is gonna be a dynamically assigned value at the place where the `?` is.

To demonstrate fully in you corresponding route file place the following code and run the code.

```
\DB::listen(function ($sql, $bindings, $time) {
    dump($sql);
    dump($time);
    dump($bindings);
});
```

This will show you what are the `$bindings` that will placed at the places where the `?` are. Additionally you can listed to the query execution `$time`